# react Could not find a declaration file for module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, decibel

i am looking a libary for decibel meter
i found this libary : https://www.npmjs.com/package/decibel-meter
but somewhat it dosent work after i install it i get error that this module not found
any suggestions?
i add a picture that show this error
because i found 2 libary that i want to use them but i cant becuase this error[image]

by the way i tried to make a folder names types and inside it make a file name index.d.ts and declare the module that i use
i make this error disappear but i still cant get the function like it should be

Comment: Try installing that package too, react native sound level.

Comment: If it not obvious  i installed this package... and try to import it or use require and it still wont get this object i have the knowledge of how to use library in react